# pg_dump for pg_restore error on linux system

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to export postgreSQL DB and import on another machine. Following are the commands I use to do the task. But this throw error.

**Export comand**

```
pg_dump DB_NAME > dump_filename
```

**Import command**

```
pg_restore --verbose -d NEW_DB_NAME dump_filename
```

Which throw following error message.

```
pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid
archive
```

Can any one help me to fix this issue?

Comment: `pg_dump DB_NAME > dump_filename` generates a SQL script. You need `psql` to run it. Please read the manual

Comment: It would be better to use `pg_dump -Fc -f dump_filename DB_NAME` and get the more flexible custom archive format that works with `pg_restore` anyway.

Comment: @Daniel Vérité : This issue caused on linux machine. And the above comment is working fine. The duplicate answer is related to windows. So take necessary amendment to give linux solution also on the duplicate question.

Comment: The syntax and the options for pg_dump, pg_restore and psql are identical between Windows and Linux. The files created by pg_dump are as well. The only difference between Windows and Linux (for this problem) is that you need to specify the file *locations* differently. Everything else is identical